# RaisePropertyChanged does not call in mvvmcross

Tags: c#, mvvmcross

`RaiseProperty` does not call.I wonder what I am missing in the following code. When I debug, I see that `StartTime` got called.

```
private DateTime _startTime;
public DateTime StartTime
{
   get { return _startTime; }
   set
   {
       _startTime = value;
       // I could able to see the following line gets called when I am in debug mode 
       RaisePropertyChanged(() => StartDateTime);
    }
}
```

The following does not get called

```
private DateTime _startDateTime;
public DateTime StartDateTime
{
   get { return _startDateTime; }
   set
   {
       _startDateTime = StartDate.Add(StartTime.TimeOfDay);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you don't have any kind of `RaisePropertyChanged` in the second call or am i wrong?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly what you want. Did you expect that RaisePropertyChanged(() => StartDateTime); actually results in calling the setter of the StartDateTime property? Because that is not what RaisePropertyChanged is for.

Comment: Kevin and Peter you are right. I want `StartDateTime` to be called.

Comment: Then use StartDateTime = StartDate.Add(value.TimeOfDay); instead of RaisePropertyChanged(() => StartDateTime); RaisePropertyChanged is intended for other interested objects to handle the event.

Comment: never mind. can't delet comment

Comment: Then how could I call or trigger `StartDateTime` ?

Comment: StartDateTime should always return StartDate.Add(StartTime.TimeOfDay); so it should becomes 

public DateTime StartDateTime
{
   get { return StartDate.Add(StartTime.TimeOfDay); }
}

Whenever you do a var x = myObj.StartDateTime it will always give the correct value. You do not need a setter.

Comment: could you please put the code as an answer please rather than comment? I will allow me to review and mark as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So StartDateTime is basically a calculated property. It can be defined like this:

```
public DateTime StartDateTime 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return StartDate.Add(StartTime.TimeOfDay); 
    } 
}
```

now, when StartTime is updated or StartDate is updated you want those changes to be reflected in the UI for example. To trigger that you need the call to `RaisePropertyChanged(() => StartDateTime);`

```
private DateTime _startTime;
public DateTime StartTime
{
   get { return _startTime; }
   set
   {
       _startTime = value;
       RaisePropertyChanged(() => StartDateTime);
    }
}
```

Now when StartTime is updated, the UI will get a signal that StartDateTime is changed as well.

Your StartDate property needs to call `RaisePropertyChanged(() => StartDateTime);` as well because a change in either StartDate or StartTime leads to another value of StartDateTime.

`RaisePropertyChanged` is an implementation of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and defines an event other objects can subscribe to. In essence it means that the subscriber will get an event signalling a change of a property and that will likely result in the subscriber to re-read the property value so it can for example update the UI accordingly.

Other option would be this:

```
private DateTime _startTime;
public DateTime StartTime
{
   get { return _startTime; }
   set
   {
       _startTime = value;
       StartDateTime = StartDate.Add(_startTime.TimeOfDay)
   }
}

private DateTime _startDate;
public DateTime StartDate
{
   get { return _startDate; }
   set
   {
       _startDate = value;
       StartDateTime = _startDate.Add(StartTime.TimeOfDay)
   }
}

private DateTime _startDateTime;
public DateTime StartDateTime
{
    get { return _startDateTime; }
    set
    {
       _startDateTime = value;
       RaisePropertyChanged(() => StartDateTime);
    }
}
```

Since a modification to either StartDate or StartTime will set StartDateTime, which in turn will call `RaisePropertyChanged` for itself so the UI can reflect the changes as well.

Comment: If you want to avoid future head scratching... it is probably worth adding `RaisePropertyChanged(() => StartTime)` and `RaisePropertyChanged(() => StartDate)` calls too...

Comment: Good point. When I implement INotifyPropertyChanged I personally always raise the event for all properties. I think having a selective set of properties involved will almost certainly give headaches later on.